# How to make Facebook API batch request into async

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-batch-request

This works fine as a batch request posting to https://graph.facebook.com, with the following as the 'batch=' parameter, but how do I make it an async request?

```
[{                                                                      
  "method": "GET",
  "relative_url": "v11.0/act_xxxxxx/insights?fields=account_id%2Caccount_name..."
},
{
  "method": "GET",
  "relative_url": "v11.0/act_yyyyyy/insights?fields=account_id%2Caccount_name..."
}]
```

I have tried posting to https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/act_xxxxxx/async_batch_requests, but results are not asynchronous, and results are returned synchronously in the request result.

Comment: Any news? Have same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but the doc here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices#asynchronous suggest that you make:

- A `POST` call to `/insights` to get a `report_run_id`
- `GET` calls to `/:report_run_id` until you get a result with `async_status: "Job Completed"` and `async_percent_completion: 100`
- A `GET` call to `/:report_run_id/insights` to get your results